# Діалогове вікно: як правильно - "Відміна" чи "Скасувати", "Вихід" чи "Вийти"?

Tags: переклад, вибір-слова

Створюємо андроїд-додаток для вивчення українського правопису. Отримали відгук і не можемо вирішити, чи коректне зауваження?

Сам додаток: ["Український правопис"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prozhar.ua.spelling)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Відмінити/скасувати

Ось, що про це думає Олександр Пономарів на своєму [блозі](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2014/06/140624_opnomariv_blog21_ko)

> Російське *отмена спектакл*я перекладаємо *скасування вистави* (або
>   *спектаклю*).
>
> *Отменить спектакль – скасувати виставу* (*спектакль*), бо *відмінити* – те саме що й *змінити*. Наприклад: "Тепер я наче трохи натуру
>   відмінила" (Леся Українка).

А ось розгорнутіший варіант з [lecture.in.ua](http://lecture.in.ua/oleksandr-ponomariv-kuletura-slova-movnostilistichni-poradi.html?page=10)

> Під упливом рос. *отменять* недоречно вживають в українській мові слово
>   *відміняти* (*відмінювати*), яке озна­чає «робити щось або когось іншим,
>   змінювати»: «Без первісних тілець природа могла б самовільно, не
>   потребу­ючи праці, усе *відміняти* на краще» (М. Зеров); «Тепер я наче
>   трохи натуру *відмінила*» (Леся Українка); «Але сопілки й тамбурини
>   глухий *одмінюють* мотив» (М. Рильський). На позначення поняття
>   «визнавати, оголошувати щось не­дійсним, незаконним, припиняти дію
>   чогось» використо­вуємо слово *скасовувати* та його похідні: *скасовувати
>   (скасувати) закон, указ, вирок, заняття* тощо. Напр.: «Коли б уряд про
>   це довідався, він міг би *скасувати* самий цех за таку постанову» (З.
>   Тулуб); «Заняття в гімназії на цей день були *скасовані*» (Ю. Смолич);
>   «Звістка про *скасування* «Життя і слова» була мені сумна не тільки з
>   загальних, але й з особистих причин» (Леся Українка).

А ось одне з правил на [LanguageTool](https://community.languagetool.org/rule/show/VIDMINYTY_VS_SKASUVATY?lang=uk&subId=1):

[image]

### Вихід/вийти

Тут мені важко визначитись, може й існує якесь правило щодо надписів на кнопках, але я його не знаю. У ліфті ми нормально можемо побачити поруч із кнопкою, наприклад, "підвал", тобто іменник. З іншого боку, якщо Open і Save ми перекладаємо як "Відчинити" і "Зберегти", то має бути "Вийти".